# Hide all rows on a sheet in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to hide all rows on a spreadsheet, and then search the spreadsheet by rows for specific a specific entry, and Unhide that entry.

However, I do not know how to hide all rows on a spreadsheet, or alternatively hide all rows other than the one I don’t want hidden.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: `Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Show Criteria Row

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ShowCriteriaRow()
    
    Const SearchString As String = "Text"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    With rg
        Set fCell = .Find(SearchString, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
            xlFormulas, xlByRows)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        ws.Rows.Hidden = True
        ws.Rows(fCell.Row).Hidden = False
        If Not ws Is ActiveSheet Then
            ws.Activate
        End If
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = fCell.Row
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = fCell.Column
        fCell.Activate
    Else
        ws.Rows.Hidden = False
    End If
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveSheet
For a = 1 to .usedrange.rows.count
    If not .Cells(a, 1) Like "SpecificEntry" Then
       .Cells(a, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End With
```

It would be best practice to replace `Activesheet` with a proper sheet reference, especially if you're already using one in your code.